# Return a list of xhr requests from website in python

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to find out if there is a way to return a list of a website's xhr requests. So, for example, https://www.canada.ca/en.html has a list of 4 xhr requests:

[image: screenshot of xhr requests]

I would like to be able to save the link addresses of the xhr requests to an array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Third-party modules like `PlayWright` or `PhantomJS` allow you to bind callbacks to be triggered when a headless browser makes requests to resources.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've heard of PhantomJS before. Is there a link you could post that would point me in the right direction for how to do this with PhantomJS? I just found this: https://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html. Is that what I want?

Comment: Yes, that looks right. For `PhantomJS` I think `onResourceRequested` is the callback you want to bind. Personally, I prefer `PlayWright`, take a look at their [example](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python#intercept-network-requests).